# Factor creates levels as integers and not actual strings

Tags: r

I'm trying to convert a column in a R dataframe which is character (A, B, C) to a factor, but when I do `str(data)`, it returns `$var : factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 3,2,1,1,2...`

When I then create models using `lm`, I see `var1` and `var2`, but I was hoping to see `varA` and `varB`, for example, and not integers (so that I can confidently know what the reference group is). I'm doing this:

```
mydata2$treat <- factor(mydata2$treat, levels = c("A", "B", "C"), labels = c("A", "B", "C"))
mydata2$treat <- relevel(mydata2$treat, ref = "A")
```

Note that the column of the dataframe is already characters (A, B, C, A, B, etc). How can I display the actual levels as characters and not as integers?

Thanks

Example:

```
> dput(mydata2)
structure(list(patient = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L,
13L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 28L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 34L,
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 52L,
53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 60L, 63L, 64L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L,
74L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 84L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L,
100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L,
111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 122L, 124L,
125L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L,
137L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 150L,
157L, 158L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 169L, 170L, 171L,
172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L,
185L, 186L, 187L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L,
203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 216L, 217L,
218L, 219L, 220L, 221L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L,
230L, 235L, 237L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L,
249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 258L, 260L, 261L, 262L,
263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L,
274L, 275L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L,
290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L,
307L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 319L, 320L, 322L, 323L, 324L,
325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 337L,
338L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 348L,
350L, 352L, 355L, 357L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 366L),
    visit = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), centre = c(29L, 5L, 5L, 29L, 3L,
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 15L, 15L,
    15L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 23L, 23L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L,
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 24L, 23L,
    35L, 35L, 35L, 27L, 27L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L,
    26L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L,
    11L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 32L, 32L,
    32L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L,
    14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 31L, 31L,
    31L, 31L, 31L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
    2L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 31L,
    31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L,
    12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 40L,
    40L, 41L, 41L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
    4L, 4L, 4L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L,
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 25L,
    26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 15L, 15L, 15L,
    15L, 15L, 15L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L,
    36L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 14L,
    14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 1L, 1L,
    36L, 36L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L), treat = c("C", "B",
    "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "A", "B",
    "A", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "C", "B", "A", "C", "C", "C",
    "B", "A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A", "B",
    "A", "C", "C", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C", "B",
    "C", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "A", "C",
    "B", "C", "C", "B", "C", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C",
    "A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C",
    "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "B", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", "C",
    "C", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A",
    "B", "C", "C", "C", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "B", 
    "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "B",
    "B", "B", "A", "C", "A", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C",
    "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B",
    "A", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "B", "C",
    "B", "A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A",
    "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A",
    "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B", "B", "A", "C", "A",
    "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "C",
    "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C",
    "B", "B", "C", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "C", "B", "B",
    "A", "B", "A", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "A",
    "A", "B", "C", "C"), dbp = c(86L, 109L, 87L, 85L, 100L, 80L,
    90L, 100L, 94L, 80L, 85L, 80L, 100L, 102L, 98L, 84L, 83L,
    87L, 110L, 94L, 90L, 86L, 86L, 100L, 92L, 94L, 92L, 88L,
    106L, 92L, 70L, 81L, 100L, 90L, 82L, 92L, 100L, 90L, 96L,
    90L, 100L, 95L, 88L, 90L, 96L, 90L, 74L, 92L, 92L, 100L,
    72L, 116L, 90L, 94L, 86L, 86L, 92L, 94L, 90L, 85L, 90L, 90L,
    100L, 80L, 88L, 82L, 100L, 96L, 100L, 98L, 106L, 80L, 102L,
    92L, 98L, 80L, 98L, 90L, 86L, 92L, 98L, 80L, 100L, 80L, 95L,
    98L, 85L, 90L, 93L, 93L, 70L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 88L, 84L,
    90L, 80L, 96L, 90L, 86L, 80L, 84L, 86L, 85L, 80L, 85L, 90L,
    85L, 98L, 110L, 106L, 90L, 80L, 85L, 86L, 94L, 95L, 80L,
    85L, 80L, 80L, 96L, 98L, 92L, 88L, 96L, 98L, 78L, 102L, 88L,
    94L, 74L, 90L, 80L, 90L, 80L, 85L, 85L, 105L, 100L, 95L,
    100L, 80L, 70L, 96L, 84L, 88L, 105L, 100L, 85L, 105L, 85L,
    92L, 105L, 100L, 85L, 80L, 98L, 96L, 90L, 90L, 88L, 90L,
    90L, 80L, 90L, 95L, 100L, 82L, 84L, 82L, 84L, 78L, 95L, 90L,
    70L, 88L, 98L, 78L, 98L, 88L, 82L, 76L, 86L, 100L, 78L, 90L,
    86L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 80L, 82L, 104L, 80L, 86L, 84L, 92L, 100L,
    96L, 96L, 92L, 88L, 85L, 110L, 100L, 85L, 102L, 79L, 94L,
    89L, 89L, 84L, 90L, 80L, 102L, 90L, 102L, 104L, 90L, 90L,
    102L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 80L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 92L, 92L, 108L,
    90L, 80L, 80L, 90L, 95L, 80L, 90L, 80L, 90L, 70L, 85L, 90L,
    80L, 92L, 98L, 82L, 85L, 80L, 85L, 76L, 80L, 84L, 80L), dbpBas = c(97L,
    117L, 100L, 105L, 114L, 105L, 100L, 102L, 105L, 100L, 100L,
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 98L, 101L, 98L, 102L, 104L, 102L,
    96L, 98L, 102L, 104L, 104L, 100L, 105L, 100L, 100L, 105L,
    101L, 100L, 112L, 100L, 102L, 114L, 105L, 108L, 105L, 110L,
    100L, 102L, 102L, 100L, 96L, 104L, 114L, 96L, 100L, 100L,
    100L, 100L, 102L, 104L, 102L, 102L, 106L, 105L, 110L, 100L,
    110L, 105L, 100L, 105L, 100L, 95L, 102L, 98L, 105L, 115L,
    95L, 104L, 115L, 105L, 95L, 104L, 96L, 114L, 102L, 108L,
    105L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
    100L, 105L, 100L, 100L, 110L, 105L, 110L, 104L, 100L, 100L,
    96L, 92L, 104L, 96L, 105L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 95L, 112L, 114L,
    114L, 102L, 110L, 110L, 104L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
    100L, 104L, 100L, 108L, 100L, 98L, 98L, 110L, 100L, 100L,
    104L, 100L, 105L, 100L, 105L, 105L, 100L, 105L, 105L, 100L,
    100L, 100L, 100L, 104L, 110L, 108L, 95L, 110L, 105L, 95L,
    98L, 105L, 95L, 105L, 95L, 100L, 102L, 96L, 108L, 110L, 104L,
    105L, 102L, 105L, 110L, 100L, 100L, 102L, 100L, 98L, 98L,
    96L, 100L, 105L, 100L, 100L, 110L, 100L, 100L, 104L, 100L,
    106L, 105L, 100L, 95L, 102L, 95L, 105L, 102L, 102L, 106L,
    104L, 108L, 108L, 104L, 102L, 102L, 112L, 110L, 104L, 106L,
    96L, 95L, 110L, 105L, 105L, 103L, 105L, 103L, 99L, 102L,
    103L, 98L, 100L, 100L, 98L, 96L, 102L, 110L, 95L, 110L, 100L,
    105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 105L, 110L, 105L, 105L, 100L, 104L,
    98L, 108L, 100L, 100L, 110L, 105L, 100L, 105L, 110L, 95L,
    100L, 105L, 110L, 100L, 98L, 104L, 102L, 98L, 105L, 100L,
    110L, 110L, 100L, 100L), cf = c(NA, NA, 3L, 3L, 1L, NA, 1L,
    NA, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 5L, NA, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
    2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, NA,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L,
    1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA,
    1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), cfBas = c(1L,
    5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L,
    5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
    1L, 1L)), row.names = c(4L, 9L, 13L, 17L, 21L, 25L, 29L,
33L, 37L, 44L, 48L, 52L, 56L, 60L, 69L, 73L, 77L, 84L, 90L, 94L,
98L, 104L, 108L, 112L, 116L, 120L, 124L, 128L, 132L, 136L, 140L,
144L, 148L, 152L, 156L, 160L, 164L, 168L, 172L, 176L, 180L, 185L,
189L, 193L, 198L, 202L, 206L, 210L, 214L, 220L, 224L, 228L, 233L,
240L, 244L, 248L, 252L, 256L, 260L, 264L, 268L, 272L, 276L, 280L,
284L, 288L, 292L, 296L, 300L, 304L, 308L, 312L, 316L, 320L, 324L,
328L, 332L, 336L, 340L, 344L, 348L, 355L, 359L, 363L, 367L, 371L,
375L, 379L, 383L, 387L, 391L, 395L, 399L, 403L, 407L, 414L, 418L,
422L, 426L, 430L, 434L, 438L, 442L, 446L, 451L, 456L, 460L, 466L,
470L, 474L, 480L, 484L, 488L, 492L, 496L, 500L, 504L, 508L, 512L,
516L, 520L, 524L, 528L, 532L, 536L, 540L, 544L, 549L, 553L, 557L,
561L, 565L, 569L, 573L, 577L, 581L, 585L, 589L, 593L, 597L, 601L,
605L, 609L, 613L, 625L, 629L, 633L, 639L, 643L, 647L, 651L, 655L,
659L, 663L, 667L, 671L, 675L, 679L, 683L, 687L, 691L, 694L, 700L,
706L, 710L, 714L, 718L, 722L, 726L, 730L, 734L, 738L, 742L, 746L,
750L, 754L, 758L, 762L, 766L, 770L, 774L, 778L, 782L, 786L, 790L,
794L, 798L, 802L, 806L, 810L, 814L, 818L, 822L, 826L, 830L, 834L,
838L, 842L, 846L, 850L, 854L, 858L, 862L, 866L, 873L, 877L, 881L,
885L, 889L, 893L, 897L, 901L, 905L, 909L, 913L, 917L, 921L, 925L,
929L, 933L, 937L, 946L, 950L, 956L, 960L, 964L, 968L, 972L, 976L,
980L, 984L, 988L, 992L, 996L, 1000L, 1004L, 1008L, 1012L, 1016L,
1020L, 1024L, 1028L, 1032L, 1036L, 1040L, 1044L, 1048L, 1052L,
1056L, 1060L, 1064L, 1068L, 1072L, 1076L, 1080L, 1084L, 1088L,
1092L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? Factors are stored internally as integers, but are generally displayed and printed as characters (except when you look at the internals with `str()`). For example, using the built-in `iris` data, in `lm(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)` the `Species` does not show up as integers. We can relevel as you do, `iris$Species = relevel(iris$Species, ref = "virginica")`, and run the model again for another nicely labeled result: `lm(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)`.

Comment: This is the intended behavior of `factor` in R. It essentially maps unique values in your data to integers, which can reduce the memory your character data takes up and speed up manipulation operations (assuming your data are comprised of a small set of unique values). See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/factor. If you want to use the values themselves, you may need to use `as.character()`

Comment: Hey added a dput straight from my data sample!

Comment: Thanks for the data. When I import your data and run you two lines of code making `treat` a factor and releveling it, and then I run `lm(dbp ~ treat + dbpBas, data = mydata2)` the coefficient names are `(Intercept), treatB, treatC, dbpBas` as I would expect.  I see no issues where there are integers instead of A, B, C. Could you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: When I run `model1_1 <- lm(dbp ~ 1 + dbpBas + treat + centre, data = mydata2, contrasts = list(treat = contr.sum, centre = contr.sum))`, and do the `summary(model1_1)` I'm seeing `treat1` and `treat2` instead of `treatB` and `treatC` for example. Could it be related with the fact that I'm using sum of contrasts? The reference level when I do model1_1$contrasts is treatment C

Comment: Yup, if you run your code with and without the `contr.sum`, you'll see that it changes the behavior of how the coefficients are named. Frankly, now that the issue is isolated, I'd recommend asking a new question with a very specific title like "How can I get model coefficients with factor levels when using sum contrasts?" and use the `iris` data to illustrate the problem so it's very clear and easy for people to help.